# GestureRecognizer throws exception in WP Direct3D App

Tags: c++, c++11, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, windows-10

I'm working on the graphic app for WP10 now. I need to use GestureRecognizer to move and to resize the objects on the screen. Looks kinda cool, but in some cases with two finger gestures, GestureRecognizer throws this error.

**WinRT information: Packets in the frame are inconsistent. Either pointer ids are not unique or there is a discrepancy in timestamps, frame ids, pointer types or source devices.**

Everything is OK with one finger gestures. The strange thing here is that this logic works fine on WP8.1.

This is source code of my RecognizerHelper:

```
GestureHelper::GestureHelper(){
    this->recognizer = ref new GestureRecognizer();

    this->recognizer->GestureSettings = GestureSettings::ManipulationScale | GestureSettings::ManipulationTranslateX |
    GestureSettings::ManipulationTranslateY | GestureSettings::Tap | GestureSettings::ManipulationRotate | GestureSettings::DoubleTap;

    this->recognizer->Tapped += ref new TypedEventHandler<GestureRecognizer ^, TappedEventArgs ^>(this, &GestureHelper::OnTapped);
    this->recognizer->ManipulationStarted += ref new TypedEventHandler<GestureRecognizer ^, ManipulationStartedEventArgs ^>(this, &GestureHelper::OnManipulationStarted);
    this->recognizer->ManipulationCompleted += ref new TypedEventHandler<GestureRecognizer ^, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs ^>(this, &GestureHelper::OnManipulationCompleted);
    this->recognizer->ManipulationUpdated += ref new TypedEventHandler<GestureRecognizer ^, ManipulationUpdatedEventArgs ^>(this, &GestureHelper::OnManipulationUpdated);
}

void GestureHelper::ProcessPress(PointerPoint ^ppt){
    this->recognizer->ProcessDownEvent(ppt);
    if (this->Clicked) {
        this->Clicked(ppt->Position.X, ppt->Position.Y);
    }
}

void GestureHelper::ProcessMove(PointerPoint ^ppt){
    this->recognizer->ProcessMoveEvents(ppt->GetIntermediatePoints(ppt->PointerId));
}

void GestureHelper::ProcessRelease(PointerPoint ^ppt){
    this->recognizer->ProcessUpEvent(ppt);
}



void GestureHelper::OnManipulationStarted(GestureRecognizer^ sender, ManipulationStartedEventArgs^ e){
    if (this->Pressed){
        this->Pressed(e->Position.X, e->Position.Y);
    }
}

void GestureHelper::OnManipulationCompleted(GestureRecognizer ^sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs ^e) {
    if (this->Released) {
        this->Released(e->Position.X, e->Position.Y);
    }
}

void GestureHelper::OnManipulationUpdated(GestureRecognizer ^sender, ManipulationUpdatedEventArgs ^e){
    if (this->MoveUpdated){
        this->MoveUpdated(e->Position.X, e->Position.Y);
    }
    if (this->ZoomUpdated){
        this->ZoomUpdated(e->Delta.Scale);
    }
    if (this->RotateUpdated) {
        this->RotateUpdated(-e->Delta.Rotation);
    }
}

void GestureHelper::OnTapped(GestureRecognizer ^sender, TappedEventArgs ^e){
    if (this->Pressed) {
        this->Pressed(e->Position.X, e->Position.Y);
    }
    if (this->Released){
        this->Released(e->Position.X, e->Position.Y);
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

**UPD:**
Try-catch is helped, but still would like to understand, why this exception throws

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have got the answer on the microsoft forum. This is the microsoft bug, that will be fixed in next updates. So now I use try catch to resolve this problem.

Answer there:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/2353edb7-8c1c-4a8d-9e57-ece72f863616/uwpgesturerecognizer-throws-exception-in-wp-direct3d-app?forum=wpdevelop